# Save input for next input

Tags: php, html

Well, I have this code:

```
<form name="download" id="download" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="beginning_date"><span class="required">*</span> Beginning Date: </label>
        <input type="text" size="30" id="beginning_date" name="beginning_date" value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y"); ?>" required="required" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="next"/>
</form>
```

and php..

```
if(array_key_exists('next', $_POST))
{
    if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/', $date))
    {
        //the code continues...
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong formation <br />";
    }
}
```

This is a long form, and I want that if someone inputs a date like this "02.03.20322", and the error appears, they don't have to start over to fill the form... the form already appears with the "fills field"...

I've already tried like these:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="beginning_date" name="beginning_date" value="<?php if (isset($date)) { echo $date; } else { echo date("d.m.Y"); } ?>" required="required" />
```

but... no changes :(

Comment: Where is your $date variable coming from? Is there more code we can't see

Comment: Where do you define `$date`?

Comment: Your idea should work, but you may have a problem with your code. Where do you set $date? array_key_exists('next' --- should that not be 'beginning_date'  ???

Comment: $beginning_date = $_POST['beginning_date'];

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, there simply is no $date so what you should check for is the existence of $_POST['beginning_date'] instead of $date like so:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="beginning_date" name="beginning_date" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['beginning_date'])) { echo $_POST['beginning_date']; } else { echo date("d.m.Y"); } ?>" required="required" />
```

Comment: $beginning_date = $_POST['beginning_date'];

Answer (score 0):

Just save it in `$_SESSION`,

at the top of page or anywhere in your action.php:

```
if (isset($_POST)){
    $_SESSION['date'] = $_POST['beginning_date'];
}
```

and then:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="beginning_date" name="beginning_date" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['date'])) ? $_SESSION['date'] : date("d.m.Y");?>" required="required" />
```

Using session is useful in case that in the future you need to change your action page. but if you want to use post instead(for same page posting), just echo it:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="beginning_date" name="beginning_date" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['beginning_date'])) ? $_POST['beginning_date'] : date("d.m.Y"); ?>" required="required" />
```

Comment: The form is posting to the same page, so the data would be available in `$_POST`

Comment: i bet that the fact that the form will post to another page in the future... i hope xD

Answer (score 0):

php..

```
 session_start();
 if(array_key_exists('next', $_POST))
 {
      if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/', $date))
     {
       //the code continues... 
     }
     else{
         echo "Wrong formation <br />";
          $_SESSION['date']=$_POST['beginning_date'];
     }
   }
```

html..

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="beginning_date" name="beginning_date" value="<?php if     
   (isset($_SESSION['date'])) { echo $_SESSION['date'] } else { echo date("d.m.Y"); } ?>" 
    required="required" />
```

Comment: This is only working the second time I refresh the page... after the input all blank, after a refresh.. all good... :(

Comment: Yeah obviously, because the first time you get into page you dont have the value for $_SESSION['date'] .

Answer (score 0):

When using method post the submitted values of the user go into the `$_POST` array. The name of the form element is used as key.

So to retrieve the date submitted by the user, you should use:

```
$_POST['beginning_date']
```